# How to search for tables which has 2 common columns in a huge database in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I am working on a huge database. There is no documentation of the database. so i found this sql query to find tables which have similar column names as i wanted.

```
SELECT  c.name as ColumnName, t.name as TableName 
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%columnName%'
```

I ran this for 2 different columns names. Now i have 2 different list of tables. But how do i get common tables out of it ? I am not sure how to use join for this as it is 2 separate queries.
Basically i want to find tables which have 2 common column names and i do not know the exact column name.

Adding to it i just have read access to the database.

Comment: That SQL won't work, what is `t`?

Comment: Sorry @DavidG i had skipped a line of code there.I have added it now.

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat a query as a table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM SomeTable) AS SubQuery
```

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT  c.name as ColumnName, t.name as TableName 
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%columnName%') AS Columns1
```

Given you can do that, you can now JOIN two queries together:

```
SELECT Columns1.TableName, 
       Columns1.ColumnName AS FirstColumnName,
       Columns2.ColumnName AS SecondColumnName
FROM 
    (SELECT  c.name as ColumnName, t.name as TableName 
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%FirstColumnName%') AS Columns1
JOIN
    (SELECT  c.name as ColumnName, t.name as TableName 
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%SecondColumnName%') AS Columns2
ON Columns1.TableName = Columns2.TableName
```

Comment: You could also use INTERSECT to cut down on the code size